# unable to find correct xpath to import in googlesheet

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im trying to get data by using importxml but I'm uanle to get data XPath I used is not provide data I want to fetch. but I'm able to get same data with importhtm and mention table, but I need to use importxml to get the best match.

Here is XPath I got with inspect element tool

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/strong
```

Here is CSS Path

```
 div.container-fluid div.row-fluid div.span6 table.table.table-bordered tbody tr td strong
```

Here is CSS selector

```
div.span6:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1)
```

What i tried yet

```
=ImportXML("https://siteurl com","//*[@class='span6']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/strong")

Got Error #N/A  (Error
Imported content is empty.)
```

Comment: what's the URL?

Comment: this is private url so I can share only for few mints after that i have to delete this comment , please dont use above url in your answer. hope you got my point . Thanks

Comment: kk got it......

Comment: can you pinpoint the value you want to scrape?

Comment: Search Volume 823000  in starting in 1st table . hope you got it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(B10, "table", 1), 1, 2), "*", )*1
```

where B10 is your URL

[image: 0]